# How to print an array in ascending or descending order without disturbing the array and without using temporay array or variable for swapping?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

program should print array elements in ascending or descending order without disturbing the array and we can't use swap or any temporary variable.

```
print_sort(array, sizeofarray);
```

Comment: Is this your homework?

Comment: Are you allowed to write other functions? Otherwise it will be complicated/impossible without any temporary variables.

Comment: @mch Yes, You can write as many functions as u want.

Comment: @ShaheAnsar This isn't any kind of homework. This caught my interest when i was designing new sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Partial) solution in the [C99 Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). It breaks if numbers repeat.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static bool is_smallest(const int *array, size_t size, int n, int min)
{
    assert(size != 0);

    if (size == 1)
    {
        if (array[0] <= min)
            return n > min;

        return n <= array[0];
    }

    return (array[0] <= min ? n > min : n <= array[0]) &&
        is_smallest(array + 1, size - 1, n, min);
}

static void print_sort2(const int *array, size_t size, size_t index, int min)
{
    if (index >= size)
        return;

    if (is_smallest(array, size, array[index], min))
    {
        printf("%d ", array[index]);
        print_sort2(array, size, 0, array[index]);
    }
    else
        print_sort2(array, size, index + 1, min);
}

static void print_sort(const int *array, size_t size)
{
    print_sort2(array, size, 0, INT_MIN);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    const int array[] = {-100, 32, -1, 4, 66, 0, -5, -500, 2};
    const size_t size = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];

    print_sort(array, size);
    print_sort((const int []){1, 5, 4, 2, 3}, 5);
    print_sort((const int []){1, 2, 3}, 3);
    print_sort((const int []){10, -10, 20, 30, 0}, 5);
}
```

Comment: So you have a recursive method that returns the nth smallest item, and you call it n times? Interesting solution, although it's going to blow the stack if the array is large.

Comment: @JimMischel My "solution" is by no means practical, but merely an attempt to meet the OP's strict requirements (taken as a challenge). Besides, it has the "eat duplicate values" bug, so I'm waiting to see a proper solution by another.

Comment: @user7023624 Thanks for your solution. Now i will try to make changes so that it can run for arrays with duplicate recurring numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Use pointers of the array and use an offset value to access the array value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   /* an array with 5 elements */
   double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
   double *p;
   int i;

   p = balance;

   /* output each array element's value */
   printf( "Array values using pointer\n");

   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      printf("*(p + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(p + i) );
   }

   printf( "Array values using balance as address\n");

   for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      printf("*(balance + %d) : %f\n",  i, *(balance + i) );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_an_array.htm

Comment: And how does this output the items in ascending order? The OP's requested output is either `[2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0, 1000.0]`, or the reverse of that. Your code does not do anything to order the items.

Comment: also `p` and `i` are temporary variables, which are not allowed.